# Why am I getting the output as None?

Tags: python

I've been trying to check whether the numbers in a list of numbers are between -1,000,000 to 1,000,000.

This is how I approached the problem, I first initialized 'check' = *True* and an array of integers named A. I then loop through the array to check whether each number is in the range or not. 'check' is set to *True* if it is and *False* if it isn't. I then return the check value at the end of the loop. I proceed to call the function and I am trying to use the check value from the function to determine whether to sort the loop or print "Out of range!" I am not really sure what I'm missing.

```
check = True
A = [10, 3, 600000000, 3, 2]

def solution(A):
    
    for num in A:
        if(-1000000 <= num <= 1000000):            
            check = True
                
        else:                
            check = False
            break
    return check

solution(A)

if(check == True):
    print(A.sort())
else:
    print("Out of range!")
```

Comment: `A.sort()` does an in place sort, it returns None, use `print(sorted(A))` or do `A.sort()` then do `print(A)`

Comment: Your `solution` function is working with a local variable `check`, which is not connected to the global `check` in any way.

Comment: assign the variable that is returned to check again. Right now, your check will always be true. That being said, what you are printing will always be None.

Answer (score 1):

Variable that is defined in a block is available in that block only. It is not accessible outside the block.

```
def solution(A):
    
    for num in A:
        if(-1000000 <= num <= 1000000):            
            check = True
                
        else:                
            check = False
            break
    return check
```

So your check value here is not accessible outside of Solution function. Since your function already returns check. Simply

```
check = solution(A)
```

To save your check outside the function.

And about printing,
according to comment by @python_learner

```
print(A.sort())
```

A.sort() does an in place sort, it returns None, use print(sorted(A)) or do A.sort() then do print(A)

Comment: Do add a little more explanation on how local and global variables work and why you have to reassign it back. Also this will still print None as he printing `<array>.sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

`A.sort()` sorts the contents of `A`, but it's return value is `None`.

```
>>> A = [5, 3, 6, 4]
>>> return_value = A.sort()
>>> print(A)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> print(return_value)
None
```

If you need to print sorted list `A`, then you should use

```
print(sorted(A))
```

instead of

```
print(A.sort())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sort syntax was incorrect and returned none as pointed out in the comments. Also you were using a global variable which defeats the purpose of using functions (modularity). Code below is more efficient and readable.

```
#Check if number 'A' is within range
A = [10, 3, 600000000, 3, 2]

def solution(A):    
    for num in A:
        if(num > 1000000 or num < -1000000):        
            return False
    return True

if(solution(A) == True):
    print(sorted(A)) # Fixed sort syntax
else:
    print("Out of range!")
```

Output:

[image]

Alternative input [10,3,3,-3]:

[image]